# Inserting Table from one MySQL Database to another - Operand should contain 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO db1.categories (c_i_parent, c_s_label, c_s_description) 
SELECT (c_i_parent, c_s_label, c_s_description) FROM db2.categories;
```

Error:

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

I am logged in onto the same server and have access to both DB's.

can someone explain why this error applies here?  I believe I have matching columns

Basically I am trying to merge two tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the parentheses from around the select list (it is syntactically incorrect, as it attempts to create a single resulting column from an expression that comprises the contents of the parentheses):

```
INSERT INTO db1.categories (c_i_parent, c_s_label, c_s_description) 
SELECT c_i_parent, c_s_label, c_s_description FROM db2.categories;
```